# 32-bit access engine

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a ssis project being developed on visual studio 2012 and it works fine on a localhost. When I upload it to sql server and try to run it as a ssis job, it throws such an error:

> The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is not
>   registered. if the 64-bit driver is not installed ,run the package in
>   32-bit mode. Error code:

I am going solve the error by installing Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable, but guess that after installing the engine all the running jobs which use current version of an engine , will be crashed. is there a way to fix it without installing 64-bit engine on sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a property of the Job to "Use 32-bit runtime", so you can run that specific job step in 32-bit. It is located under the `Execution options` tab of the Job step.
I don't believe other packages are affected when you install the 32-bit Redistributable.

Comment: Thank a lot ! I have been trying to fine a solution for three days already. I have reinstalled ole drivers on the localhost and on the sql server a lot of times. but your way is great.

Comment: Great I could be of help! :-)